# awk - backticks in solaris to accept command line arg

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have this script that is meant to trim the field specified as argument to the script.
ie `sh script.sh file.txt "|" 2`

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
delim="$2"
arg="$3"
gsubber="\"gsub("^[ \t]*|[ \t]*$","",'\$$arg')\""
myout=`nawk -F"$delim" -v fl="$gsubber" \'{ { fl } }1\' OFS="$delim" "$filename"`
echo "$myout"
```

So this file 'file.txt' as input:

```
sid|storeNo|latitude
9| gerdy| fd¿kjhn422-405
0000543210 |gfdjk39
gfd|fd||fd
```

becomes this output:

```
sid|storeNo|latitude
9|gerdy| fd¿kjhn422-405
0000543210 |gfdjk39
gfd|fd||fd
```

I get this error:
nawk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is

> > > ' <<<
> > >               missing }
> > >       nawk: bailing out at source line 1

Once someone can assist with providing the correct syntax, I should have no trouble extending it to support multiple fields. ie `sh script.sh file.txt "|" 2 3` could then trim the 2nd and 3rd field only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please check: `echo $gsubber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1
delim=$2
arg=$3
regex='^[ \t]*|[ \t]*$'
myout=$(
  nawk -F"$delim" -v regex="$regex" -v arg="$arg" '
    { gsub(regex, "", $arg) }
    1' OFS="$delim" "$filename"
  )

printf '%s\n' "$myout"
```

Edit:

In order to handle multiple fields in the arguments (see comments below):

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1 
delim=$2
shift 2
args=$@
regex='^[ \t]*|[ \t]*$'
myout=$(
  nawk -F"$delim" -v regex="$regex" -v args="$args" '{ 
    n = split(args, t, " ")
    for (i = 0; ++i <=n;)
      gsub(regex, "", $t[i]) 
    }1' OFS="$delim" "$filename"
  )

printf '%s\n' "$myout"
```

Comment: Problem is this will not support multiple arguments. my idea is to then be able to have a gsub for each numeric argument inputted to the script. ie sh script.sh file.txt "|" 4 7 would need the following: gsub(/^[ \t]*|[ \t]*$/,"",$4) gsub(/^[ \t]*|[ \t]*$/,"",$7)

Comment: Hi @toop, I've just added a solution for this.

Comment: perhaps you would be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700075/pl-sql-can-collection-loop-through-column-names

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
delim="$2"
arg="$3"
myout=`nawk -F"$delim" -v f="$arg"  '{gsub(/^[ \t]*|[ \t]*$/,"",$f) }1' OFS="$delim" "$filename"`
echo "$myout"
```

you don't have to extract gsub out, since in the gsub function call, only field index is variable. you could pass the field index as var to awk.

Comment: I do have extract the gsub out because I want to then pass in multiple arguments. ie sh script.sh file.txt "|" 4 7 would need the following: gsub(/^[ \t]*|[ \t]*$/,"",$4) gsub(/^[ \t]*|[ \t]*$/,"",$7) But the number of arguments is unknown till run time so my idea was to create a loop of gsubs for each numeric argument inputted.